# jquery load event on create image dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am using load event for retireve content of one page to another page. Below the content of main page

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content" id="container">
    <div class="sub_nav" id="sub_nav">
        <div class="sub_dyn">
            <img id="menu_project_tool" src="images/menu-btn.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vs-context-menu nav" id="nav"></div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="clearfix_bot">
            <div class="main_sidebar"></div>
            <div class="right_sidebar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

And this is script which i used on main page

```
window.onload = function(){
    $("div.header").load("header.html");
    $("div.main_sidebar").append('<div class="project_steps"></div>');
    $("div.main_sidebar").append('<div class="project_subset_criterion"></div>');
    $("div.right_sidebar").append('<div class="project_subset_criterion_accordion"></div>');
    $("div.project_steps").load("temp/project_steps.html");
    $("div.project_subset_criterion").load("temp/project_subset_criterion.html");
    $("div.project_subset_criterion_accordion").load("temp/project_subset_criterion_accordion.html");
    $("div.footer").load("footer.html");

    Create_Image('<img />','new_sc_tool','images/icons/NewStarburst.gif','New Subset Criterion');

}


$(document).ready(function(){

    Create_Image = function(Type,Id,Src,Title){
                        $(Type, {id:Id, src:Src, title:Title}).appendTo("#toolbar_subset_criterion");
                   }

});
```

i have call "Create_Image" function to create dynamic image on second page but it can't work. But i add alert box in above function to check function is called or not, in which condition image is created but remave that alert box image isn't created. this is my second page content where i have create the image dynamically

```
<div class="heading_subset_criterion">
    <img id="scimg_arrow_down" src="images/arrow_down.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Project Subset Criterion</b>
</div>

<div class="toolbar_subset_criterion" id="toolbar_subset_criterion"></div>

<div class="content_subset_criterion"></div>
```

give me any idea to complete the above event

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're loading the second page using ajax and injecting it to the main page and then you want to add an `img` element to the injected html, is that right? In that case, the problem is that the html hasn't been loaded when you try to add the `img`. Instead of using the `document.ready` event, add a success-handler to the ajax-call.

Assuming `#toolbar_subset_criterion` is in the header, this should do it:

```
$("div.header").load("header.html", function() {
    Create_Image('<img />','new_sc_tool','images/icons/NewStarburst.gif','New Subset Criterion');
});
```